# Sorting through strings in array?

Tags: vb.net

Each array string represents a text file in a folder. I want the array to be sorted based on what the text file contains. How would I do that?

Comment: First you need to look at whats in each file. Loop through the strings, look at the file, and figure out what position it should be in. That should get you started.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a custom `Comparison` to `Array.Sort`, so just read the file there:

```
Array.Sort(str, Function(a, b)
                    Dim aContents As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(a)
                    Dim bContents As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(b)

                    'Compare the contents and return -1 if a < b, 0 if a = b, or 1 if a > b.
                End Function)
```

If efficiency is an issue there, you may want to cache the contents of each file in a `Dictionary` or do something similar.

---

Also, you can go LINQ, depending on what exactly it is in the files you need to sort by:

```
Dim result = str.
    Select(Function(x) New With {.File = x, .Contents = IO.File.ReadAllText(x)}).
    OrderBy(Function(y) y.Contents)
```

... for example.